# Android WebView pinch zoom scale lower than 1.0

Tags: android, webview, scale, pinchzoom

I have a WebView displaying some local images:

```
private void setupWebView(MyWebView pWebView) {
    pWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    pWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    pWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    pWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    pWebView.setSaveEnabled(true);
    pWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    pWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    pWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    pWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    pWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    pWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    pWebView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

}
```

and the header meta-tags:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=0.784, minimum-scale=0.783, maximum-scale=1.300, user-scalable=yes, target-densityDpi=device-dpi' />
```

On some devices e.g. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 with Android 4.1.1 I can use the Zoom Controlls to zoom from 0.783 to 1.3. But if I use the pinch geasture the scale jumps directely to 1.0 (if it was lower) and I can zoom only from 1.0 to 1.3.

If I zoomed out to 1.0, with scale geature, zoom out button is diasbled as well. I need to zoom in to 1.3 using zoom controls or pinch geasture to be able to zoom out to 0.783 with zoom controls again.

Did someone else have the some problem or has found a solution? I have no idea where this comes from. On Samsung Galaxy S4 the pinch geasture works without problems.

UseWideViewPort is disabled by intent. Otherwise the min and max scales are ingored.